# Fetch returning 401 but console shows 200

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I'm making a fetch request as follows and notice that console message from error being printed as

```
fetch(FI_API),
      { credentials: 'include' })
         .then(r => r.json())
         .then(res => console.log(res))
          .catch((e) => {
            console.log(e);
          });       

Failed to load https://FI_API/api/company/search?q=fac: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://mdcds.ok.com:3001' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
SuggestCheck.tsx:91 TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

But i notice in Chrome console that the request does indeed complete with 200 and the response has values as expected. Is there a way to ignore 401 and get results from 200 returned after that?

Comment: did you try to log\debug after each promise? and not only in the end, maybe the response is ok but something inside your code is wrong

Comment: No the code is correct in client end. Something is off in server side i believe,.